# Computer vision algorithm to use for making lines thinner

Tags: computer-vision

I have lecture notes written by a professor using a stylus.

A sample:
[image: lecture-notes-sample]

The width of the line used here is making reading difficult for me. I would like to make the lines thinner. The only solution I could think of is dilating the image. This gives a passable result:
[image: lecture-notes-dilated]

The picture above is with uniform kernel of shape (2, 2) applied once; I've tried a bunch of kernel types, widths & numbers of iterations to arrive at this version that looks best to me.

However, I can't help but wonder if there's maybe another applicable algorithm that I'm missing; one that could lead to even better results? I wasn't able to google any computer vision approaches to font thinning, so I would appreciate any information on the subject.

Comment: Yeah, it's useless task so no-one want to do that. i guess GAN (pix2pix, cygcleGAN, etc) can solve this task.

Comment: @VuGiaTruong GAN seems like an overkill, I don't want to procrastinate that much... :)

Answer (score 1):

Have been monitored such info during several days. Try to use Thinning described [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/morops.htm), the link is also in the references to [OpenCV-Python-Tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) on morphological transforms. Taking [Image Gradient](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_gradients/py_gradients.html) can help, but it will make the image Grayscale, and with inverting colors you can get black-on-white text. Try to leave original color on black pixels location when original and final images are stacked.